# side-by-side configuration error in flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run the Flutter app on the Chrome "flutter run -d Chrome"

but every time throw this error :

```
"ProcessException: The application has failed to     
start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event 
log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

I ran flutter doctor -v and there is no problem, I ran the app both on vscode and android-studio, and both had the same problem. I believe this is a Chrome issue or windows issue but not sure how I can solve it.

[image]

Comment: facing issue in windows 10 ?

Comment: Yes, I also deactivated chrome pop-up blockers but still doesn't work

Comment: check out this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ3FXdXJPhM

Comment: Hi, Tried this one didn't work.

Comment: this is not flutter issue this issue coming from your OS : https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&checkda=1&ct=1636698365&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Fanswers.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsite%2Fcompletesignin%3Fsilent%3DTrue%26returnUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fanswers.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Fwindows%252Fforum%252Fall%252Fthe-application-has-failed-to-start-because-the%252F5c6a015e-4162-491d-b7d9-f3b13612e304&id=273572&aadredir=1